# anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking) error in unity animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Unity learn section - survival shooter, I am getting an error shows the following error

> Type "UnityEngine.Animation" does not contain a definition for "SetBool" and no extension method "SetBool" of type "UnityEngine.Animation" could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I have checked the name of files and components.

## Code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;

    Vector3 movement;
    Animation anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floorMask;
    float camRayLength = 100f;

    void Awake()
    {
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Verticle");

        Move(h, v);
        Turning();
        Animating(h, v);
    }

    void Move(float h, float v)
    {
        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Turning()
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast (camRay ,out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
        
        }
    }

    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h!= 0f || v!= 0f;
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message. The error message leads me to ask you: Why would you think that an `Animation` object (your _anim_ is an object of type Animation) has a `SetBool` method? Check the documentation for the `Animation` type: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html. Can you see it having a SetBool method?

Answer (score 5):

The character's animation controller is of type `Animator`, not `Animation`.  Use `SetBool` on `Animator`.

```
Animator anim;

void Awake()
{
    // ...
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    // ...
}
```